# Still cant access localhost:5762 after starting RabbitMQ server

Tags: java, spring, macos, rabbitmq

Tried accessing the RabbitMQ management page on localhost:5672 and the connection is being refused. I have reinstalled RabbitMQ via Homebrew and still running into the same problem. I ran `rabbitmq-server` after the reinstallation and got back this prompt:

```
##  ##      RabbitMQ 3.8.1
  ##  ##
  ##########  Copyright (c) 2007-2019 Pivotal Software, Inc.
  ######  ##
  ##########  Licensed under the MPL 1.1. Website: https://rabbitmq.com

  Doc guides: https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html
  Support:    https://rabbitmq.com/contact.html
  Tutorials:  https://rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html
  Monitoring: https://rabbitmq.com/monitoring.html

  Logs: /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log
        /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost_upgrade.log

  Config file(s): (none)

  Starting broker... completed with 6 plugins.
```

Not sure why I cant access the management page via the default port. I had a few applications using RabbitMQ running and none of them are working now. What is the best way to completely uninstall RabbitMQ from a Mac so that I can run a clean install?

Comment: The management interface is on port 15762, not 5672. Port 5672 is used for accessing RabbitMQ via AMQP (the message queueing protocol). Try starting the server and pointing your browser to `localhost:15672`.

Comment: @Jesper Oh I see, I've been using Port 5672 and it stopped working all of a sudden. Still, I'm getting a similar connection refused error on Port 15672 and none of my Java applications that use RabbitMQ are working.

Comment: Do you have / know Docker? Because it's super-easy to run RabbitMQ in Docker, and then you don't need to (re)install it on your computer. See [RabbitMQ docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq).

Comment: Starting it in Docker can be done with a command like this: `docker run -d -h rabbitmq --name rabbitmq -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3.8.1-management`

Answer (score 2):

I think you should have to enable management plugin as stated in rabbitmq documention:

> The management plugin is included in the RabbitMQ distribution. Like any other plugin, it must be enabled before it can be used.

Just go to your rabbitmq installation directory (example path `/usr/save/rabbitmq_server-x.x.x/sbin`) and run following command:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

After this if rabbitmq management still not accessible try to  `stop` and `restart` rabbitmq server.

Here are reference link:

[Rabbitmq documention on management plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html)

[Rabbitmq different networking ports information](https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html#ports)

Answer (score 0):

To answer these:

> Not sure why I cant access the management page via the default port.
>
> Still cant access localhost:5762 after starting RabbitMQ server

If the `rabbitmqctl status` / `rabbitmq-diagnostics status` command shows a listener like this:

```
Interface: [::], port: 15672, protocol: http, purpose: HTTP API
```

then RabbitMQ [might](https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-networking.html) be setup correctly.

### Probable cause: Http redirection

The issue might rather be with the URL that's visited. Chrome could be set to redirect HTTP to HTTPS. If this is so, and you don't have an HTTPS listener setup, you'd see a `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`.
To get around this, you can disable redirection on Chrome only for `localhost`. By doing so, http://localhost:15672 will no longer be redirected to https://localhost:15672 and the management web client will therefore be visible.

### [How](https://howchoo.com/chrome/stop-chrome-from-automatically-redirecting-https) to disable HTTP redirection for a domain in Chrome

1. Visit `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`
2. Delete domain security policies for the domain (in this case simply enter `localhost`)
3. Click the `Delete` button